# Can I write a character of string on JButton?

Tags: java, string, swing, user-interface, awt

I wanna create a word game. I'll give the word that is not in order. The gamer will find the correct word. I made three button that have the same background. And I have a string for example BOX. Can I write 'B' to buton1 then 'O' to buton2. I'm confused because they must have a background. Please help thanks

```
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;

public class Example extends JFrame {
     private static Example main;

        public static void main (String[] args){


        main = new Example();

    JLabel backGround = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("C:\\he\\main2.png"));
    main.setTitle("FiHa");
    main.setSize(750, 550);
    main.getContentPane().add(backGround);
    main.setLocationRelativeTo(null); // Center the frame
    main.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    main.setVisible(true);
    main.setResizable(false);


    }

    public Example() {
      setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("C:\\he\\iconfh.png"));


       ImageIcon ikon=new ImageIcon("C:\\he\\bx.png");

       String word1 ="BOX";

        JButton btn1 = new JButton("1");
        btn1.setBounds( 150, 300, 100,100);
        btn1.setIcon(ikon);
        this.add(btn1);

        JButton btn2 = new JButton("2");
        btn2.setBounds( 290, 300, 100,100);
        btn2.setBackground(Color.pink);
        btn2.setIcon(ikon);
        this.add(btn2);

        JButton btn3 = new JButton("3");
        btn3.setBounds( 430, 300, 100,100);
        btn3.setBackground(Color.pink);
        btn3.setIcon(ikon);
        this.add(btn3);
    }



}
```

Comment: sure. setText, or by passing it in the constructor

Comment: `Character.toString`?

Comment: Avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify

Comment: I used setText. No syntax error but cahnged nothing

Answer (score 1):

you can use button.setText("button name");

```
public class Example extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    private static Example main;
    JButton btn1, btn2, btn3;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {


    main = new Example();

    JLabel backGround = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("C:\\he\\main2.png"));
    main.setTitle("FiHa");
    main.setSize(750, 550);
    main.getContentPane().add(backGround);
    main.setLocationRelativeTo(null); // Center the frame
    main.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    main.setVisible(true);
    main.setResizable(false);


    }

    public Example()
    {
    setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("C:\\he\\iconfh.png"));


    ImageIcon ikon = new ImageIcon("C:\\he\\bx.png");

    String word1 = "BOX";

    btn1 = new JButton("1");
    btn1.setBounds(150, 300, 100, 100);
    btn1.setBackground(Color.pink);
    btn1.setIcon(ikon);
    this.add(btn1);
    btn1.addActionListener(this);
    btn1.setActionCommand("1");

    btn2 = new JButton("2");
    btn2.setBounds(290, 300, 100, 100);
    btn2.setBackground(Color.pink);
    btn2.setIcon(ikon);
    this.add(btn2);
    btn2.addActionListener(this);
    btn2.setActionCommand("2");

    btn3 = new JButton("3");
    btn3.setBounds(430, 300, 100, 100);
    btn3.setBackground(Color.pink);
    btn3.setIcon(ikon);
    this.add(btn3);
    btn3.addActionListener(this);
    btn3.setActionCommand("3");
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
    JButton btn = (JButton) e.getSource();
    if (btn.getActionCommand().equals("1"))
    {
        btn1.setText("B");
    }
    else if (btn.getActionCommand().equals("2"))
    {
        btn2.setText("o");
    }
    else if (btn.getActionCommand().equals("3"))
    {
        btn3.setText("x");
    }


    }
```